# Exportar dataset em excel asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, response

Criei um programa para exportar um Dataset para excel em tempo de execução via Response, porém ao abrir o arquivo é exibida uma mensagem de incompatibilidade entre o formato do arquivo e a extensão do mesmo.

Segue código:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();            

int IdEmpresa = this.Master.UsuarioLogado.IdEmpresa;
UpQuesitoRespostaBLL uqr = new UpQuesitoRespostaBLL();
List<UpQuesitoCargoResposta> lstOpcoesRespostas = uqr.ListarOpcoesRespostasPorEmpresa(IdEmpresa);
int qtdeRespostas = lstOpcoesRespostas.FirstOrDefault().Respostas.Count();

dt.Columns.Add("Quesito");
dt.Columns.Add("Area");
dt.Columns.Add("Cargo");
dt.Columns.Add("Peso");
for (int i = 1; i <= qtdeRespostas; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Valor_" + i);
    dt.Columns.Add("Resposta_" + i);
}
foreach (var resp in lstOpcoesRespostas)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row[0] = resp.DsQuesito.ToString();
    row[1] = resp.DsArea.ToString();
    row[2] = resp.DsCargo.ToString();
    row[3] = resp.Peso.ToString();
    int j = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < qtdeRespostas; i++)
    {
        row[j + 1] = resp.Respostas[i].Valor.ToString();
        row[j + 2] = resp.Respostas[i].DsResposta.ToString();
        j += 2;
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

ds.Tables.Add(dt);

StringWriter sw = DataSetToExcel(ds);

string date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "-").ToString();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=RespostasPerformance" + date + ".xls");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Já modifiquei o contentType e a extensão no header, porém nenhuma tentativa funcionou.

O erro está no formato ou na forma como estou exportando ?

Comment: Ele abre o arquivo depois ou não?

Comment: o arquivo abre, aparece uma mensagem dizendo que existe uma diferença entre o formato e a extensão, me pergunta se quero abrir assim mesmo. Ao clicar em Sim o arquivo abre normalmente

Comment: Tem pacote que faz isso pra você, usa eles mais fácil

Comment: @GuilhermeTavares Isso acontece por que você não está de fato construindo um arquivo excel, apenas salvando um arquivo com uma estrutura que ele consegue fazer a conversão com a extensão `.xls`.

Comment: Alguma indicação VIrgilio ?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo então você aconselha construir de uma outra forma, sem o dataset ??